# iOS get the value of CKRecordID with ID Value

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, cloudkit

I fetching all the data from iCloud but I need to get the ID of each record. If access to the metadata of recordID (CKRecord) I get:

```
po myRecord.recordID
<CKRecordID: 0x17003e3c0; 115:(_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__)>
```

But I'm only interested in the value "115".

Any of you knows how can access to the ID value?

I'll really appreciate your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the id by doing:

```
po myRecord.recordID.recordName
```